Title: Unable to Build Android Project Due to Gradle Cache Transformation Error
I am unable to build my Android project in Android Studio. When I run the project, I encounter this error:
    C:\Users\fuers\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\
    68d939a78f96db38eb7ca2cccd754cb0-ce43a2e0-d67b-4cd3-9666-b7c2d9989b8f ->
    C:\Users\fuers\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\68d939a78f96db38eb7ca2cccd754cb0

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Removed the .gradle caches and rebuilt the project.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times.
Invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio.

but i still get the error, how can I resolve it?
the error messege
dependency
the code

Please [edit] the question and provide all relevant code and error message as text, not images.

Usually this succeeds with a second or third try for me but when looking into it, it seemed to be a Gradle Bug #30069 / #28475 / #30680 which will be fixed in Gradle 8.11
Unfortunately this is not released yet but the fix is in Gradle 8.11-rc-2
I've not tried this as my error was intermittent.
